# Can't remove older version of libreoffice

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

I have both libreoffice 6.0 and 6.2 installed.in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
When I look into synaptic installer I can't find the 6.2 version but it is definitively there.
In the ubuntu software I can find both version but any attempt to remove 6.0 from there fails. Or more acurately I can remove them using the remove button and seconds later they are back.
Also tried:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice6.0* 
>   Reading package lists...
>   Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package libreoffice6.0* 
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libreoffice6.0*' 
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libreoffice6.0*'

Comment: Synaptic deals only with deb packages, did you install a snap or alternative type of package?  Ubuntu Software lists for example snaps & deb packages.  `snap list` should show what snap packages you have installed; which can be removed with `snap` commands (like `apt` & `dpkg` commands do with deb packages).  To work out why Ubuntu Software failed you'd need to look in logs, or use a command to remove it where any messages appear on screen (as well as being logged).

Comment: `Unable to locate package libreoffice6.0*`: that is because no packages with such name exist. Not sure, however, why you do not succeed removing one of the two versions using Software Center. try `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`. This will not remove the newer "snap" version.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have done the trick. And yes the 6.2 version is a snap package, learn something new everyday...